# Transaction in Virtuoso over HTTP

Tags: sparql, virtuoso, triplestore

I am trying to use transaction in [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) over HTTP SPARQL/WEB service endpoint. In [This Link](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtTipsAndTricksLoadDataInTransactionMode) they are using **isql** tool not SPARQL query and endpoint.

Is there any way to perform transaction operations over HTTP?

Comment: SPARQL does not have transactions, so it's not surprising that you cannot use the SPARQL endpoint for such. I do not think the HTTP-based implementation of iSQL supports this either. It may be helpful if you can explain what you're trying to achieve, as there may be another/better way to get there.

Comment: I have two graphs one is saving data/triples one is saving metadata related to graph. 
My use-case is first update data graph then update metadata graph. in case of failure rollback both graphs.

Comment: Are you constrained to HTTP interactions? If you can use ODBC, JDBC, ADO.NET, OLE DB, etc., transactions are definitely available. If you cannot, I suggest you raise this to the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/) or (if using Commercial Edition or with a Support Contract on Open Source Edition), an [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). (ObDisclaimer: [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/) produces [Virtuoso](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/) and employs me.)

Comment: Thank you I sent them email now.